# x86_64 Assembler read file and print it to console

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64

I have to code a program, that reads char by char of a given text file and do something with it.

First of all I want to print every char out and stop when the end of file is reached. Both things don't work. In older programs I used rax to detect when the end of file is reached, but this doesn't work in this program.
I have also the problem, that the program prints out a dot between every character when I read in char at a time. When I read more than one char at once, this problem doesn't occur.

File: Arcu scelerisque aliquam. Nullam viverra magna vitae leo. (...)

Console: $ ./wortzaehl

Output: A.r.c.u. .s.c.e.l.e.

Here is my current code:
(I used r9, because I can't detect end of file)
(I know that this code is probably totally inefficient)

```
%define STDOUT      1
%define STDIN       0
%define READONLY        0
%define SYS_READ        0
%define SYS_WRITE   1
%define SYS_OPEN    2
%define SYS_CLOSE       3
%define SYS_EXIT    60

section .data
newline:
    db 0x0a
space:
        db 0x20
tab:
        db 0x09


invalid_argument_text:
        db "No Path given"

section .bss
input_buffer:
    resb 1

section .text
    global _start

;;;================= Read/Write Functions =============================
write_invalid_arg:
    ;; save registers that are used in the code
    push    rax
    push    rdi
    push    rdx
    mov rax, SYS_WRITE
    mov rdi, STDOUT
    mov rsi, invalid_argument_text
    mov rdx, 13
    call    make_syscall
    pop rdx
    pop rdi
    pop rax
    jmp finish
    
write_newline:
    ;; save registers that are used in the code
    push    rax
    push    rdi
    push    rsi
    push    rdx
    ;; prepare arguments for write syscall
    mov rax, SYS_WRITE  ; write syscall
    mov rdi, STDOUT ; fd = 1 (stdout)
    mov rsi, newline    ; string
    mov rdx, 1      ; length

        call make_syscall

    ;; restore registers (in opposite order)
    pop rdx
    pop rsi
    pop rdi
    pop rax
    ret

write_char:
    push    rsi         ; speicher rsi
    mov rax, SYS_WRITE      ; Syscall Typ
    mov rdi, STDOUT     ; Out
    mov rsi, input_buffer   ; Aktuelle Zeile
    mov rdx, 1          ; Laenge der Zeile
    call    make_syscall        ; syscall
    pop rsi         ; Hol rsi zurueck
    ret

open_file:
        push    rdi
    push    rsi
    push    rdx
        mov     rax, SYS_OPEN      ; Datei oeffnen
        mov     rdi, rsi           ; Pfad zur Datei
        mov     rsi, READONLY      ; Nur lesen
        call    make_syscall
        mov     r11, rax
        pop     rdx
    pop     rsi
    pop     rdi
    ret

read_char:
        push    rdi
        push    rsi
        push    rdx
        mov     rdi, r11          ; Geoeffnete Datei
        mov     rax, SYS_READ
        mov     rsi, input_buffer
        mov     rdx, 1
        call    make_syscall
        pop     rdx
        pop     rsi
        pop     rdi

make_syscall:
        push    rcx     ; clobbered by syscall
    push    r11     ; clobbered by syscall
    syscall         ; system call
        pop r11
    pop rcx
    ret
; ======================================================


count_text:
        mov     r8, 0       ; Zeichen
        mov     r9, 0       ; Worte
        mov     r10, 0      ; Zeilen
        call    open_file
next_char:
        call    read_char
    
        cmp     r8, 10
        je      text_finished
    
        ;cmp        rax, 0
        ;jne        text_finished
        ;call    write_invalid_arg

        call    write_char
    
        inc     r8
    
        jmp     next_char
text_finished:
        ; Text schliessen
        mov     rax, SYS_CLOSE
        mov     rdi, r10
        call    make_syscall
        ret



;========================
_start:
    pop rbx         ; argc (>= 1 guaranteed) Anzahl Args
    
    dec rbx         ; remove command
    jz  write_invalid_arg   ; when no arg after command
    pop rsi         ; remove letters of command
    
    pop rsi         ; Pfad
    
    call   count_text
finish:
    call    write_newline
    ;; exit program via syscall exit (necessary!)
    mov rax, SYS_EXIT   ; exit syscall
    mov rdi, 0      ; exit code 0 (= "ok")
    syscall         ; kernel interrupt: system call
```

I made some tests and I think, that the input buffer does not only contain the read char. When I do the following:

```
        mov     r15b, byte [input_buffer]
    mov rsi, r15            ; Aktuelle Zeile
```

The only output are dots

EDIT: I forgot a return in read_char. Now the only problem is the detection of the end of file

Comment: not sure if that's the issue but aren't you missing `ret` in `read_char` after the `pop`s and before `make_syscall` label?

Comment: Yes, your right. That fixes the problem with the dots. I search for like an hour and didn't see this. Now the only problem is the detection of the end of file

Comment: What platform are you writing against?

Comment: I dont know what you mean. I'm using SASM Editor and a Linux Subsystem on Windows. Everything woked fine so far. I have a x86_64 processor.

Comment: @burprinz use the `cmp rax, 0` and change the `jne` to `je`. It works.

Comment: You have to look for 0 bytes returned

Answer (score 2):

I hat two problems:

1. The program prints out dots after every character
2. I can't detect the end of file

Both problems got fixed by one mistake: I forgot a 'ret' in read_char.

With

```
cmp        rax, 0
je        text_finished
```

I can now detect if the end of file is reached.

Comment: you need, `je` not `jne`

Comment: Running your program under GDB and single-stepping is a way to catch bugs like this in the future.  Seeing execution fall off the bottom of a function is very visible even without looking at register values.